# Most recent vesion of MySQL not working with a C# WinForms app

Tags: c#, mysql

I installed the most recent MySQL version in order to use it as a database for a C# windows form application.

While developing the app I used "MySQL server 5.7.17". However I installed the most recent version on another computer and the app to see how it works. But they don't seem to work propertly.

At first, I couldn't update data from the app I installed, but from Visual Studio it updates data and works perfectly. so I uninstall and reinstall MySQL but this time The app was not able to connect to MySQL; even though I install the "MySQL connector/NET".

My Question is: Should I install the same version I was using while developing or use the most recent version?

Comment: If you don't tell us what does it means _they don't seem to work properly_ it is difficult to give a reasoned answer. Do you have error messages?

Comment: The last time I checked with MySql there was no such breaking change that could give errors of this magnitude. Probably there is something in your code or your configuration.

Comment: Even after the edit, this sounds more like a rant and not a proper question. There is simply nothing for us to go on. There are lots of developers out there, who successfully managed to work with mysql from .net code. So, the cause of the problem lies either within your config or your code.

Comment: You were right it was an error in my code that was causing the query to fail when trying to update. 

Thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried catching the exception to get a better idea of what is going wrong?

I recently had the same problem after I updated the connector in nuget.

The solution was to add "SslMode=none" to the connection string.

Example string
"server=servername;uid=username;pwd=password123;database=databasename;Pooling=False;SslMode=none;"

Comment: _SslMode=none_ yup had that one as well a few days ago.

Comment: Yes I did. It was an error in my code that was causing the query to fail when trying to update. 

Thanks for your help and time.